# Can't create SharePoint 2013 credentials in C# because username is not an email address

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, credentials

Our SharePoint 2013 is available without logging in because we are logged in to Windows and the Windows credentials are passed to SharePoint.

I am creating a C# app to read lists of files in a Documents site on SharePoint and download some of them. But I've fallen at the first step. I can't create SharePoint credentials that SharePoint will accept, because the username is not an email address and SharePointOnlineCredentials will not accept a username that is not an email address. This is my current code:

```
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(UriString))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
        }
```

I have tried collecting the Network credentials,

```
var credentials2 =new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, "MyDomain");
```

but I can't convert/cast the Network credentials into SharePoint credentials.

How can I connect to SharePoint and experience the same rights that I have through Windows? (with the same username and password)

Comment: "but I can't convert/cast the Network credentials into SharePoint credentials" - are you sure you need to? The `Credentials` property is defined to take an `ICredentials`, an interface that both `SharePointOnlineCredentials` and `NetworkCredential` implement.

Comment: Thanks. I had a couple of inherited procedures with a 'credential'  parameter declared as SharePointOnlineCredentials instead of ICredentials. Once I knew what to look for it was easy to spot. After that I used NetworkCredential (as stated in the question) and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are using a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment (using windows authentication)?

For default windows authentication use DefaultNetworkCredential instead of SharePointOnlineCredentials